# Javascript function executes automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am unable to understand why these two javascript functions execute automatically when the JSP file is loaded. procChart function gets executed first and then the drawChart. I understand that drawChart is called when the Google Visualization APIs are loaded. It's intriguing how procChart is called first and then later on the next script is executed automatically. Can anyone explain ?

Code -

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function procChart(){

        <% System.out.println("Inside procChart"); %>

        var ExpList = new Array();
        ExpList = request.getParameterValues("chkExps");
        ExpList.push(request.getParameter("expId"));

        <jsp:useBean id="compare"
            class="org.server.experiment.CompareResults" />

            <%int[][] data4= compare.getResult(request.getParameter("expId"), request.getParameterValues("chkExps")  ,request.getParameter("field")); %>;
            <% System.out.println(data4); %>
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]
    });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var te= new Array();

         <% for (int i=0; i<data4.length; i++) { %>
            var xe = [];
         <% for (int j=0; j<data4[i].length; j++) { %>
            xe[<%= j %>] = <%= data4[i][j] %>;

         <% } %>
            te.push(xe);
         <% } %>

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var len = te[0].length;
        data.addColumn('string', 'Experiment');

        for(var k=0; k < te.length; k++){
            data.addColumn('number', 'Exp'+(k+1));
        }
        data.addRows(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            data.setCell(i, 0, ""+(i+1));
            for (var j = 0; j < te.length; j++) {


                data.setCell(i, j+1, te[j][i]);
            }
        }

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document
                .getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {
            width : 900,
            height : 500
        });
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the Line chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE - The code works perfectly fine and I get the desired chart. I am just curious how it is working.

Comment: since `drawChart` is an `OnLoad` event handler, its execution is delayed, giving `procChart` time to be invoked. I don't see where `procChart` is invoked though.

Comment: @cookiemonster - That's my point, I am nowhere explicitly calling procChart, but still it is called automatically and executed. I am unable to understand this behavior.

Comment: If you are not calling `procChart()` and don't use it then just delete it completely from your code and you will see who will complain.

Comment: @AntoJurković - I need procChart function to get data from the server. So it needs to be executed before drawchart is called. It happens that way in the code that I have pasted above. I just don't know why it is happening that way. I mean I never called procChart anywhere and still it is executed. If I delete procChart then drawchart will not have any data to plot.

Comment: I saw that `data4` variable. Do you have any java code in your environment which calls it?

Comment: @AntoJurković - None of the Java code calls that function. This jsp page is called from another jsp page. Then this jsp page calls the java class "compare" which is called from the procChart function.

Comment: What does your jsp code render as on the client-side?  Open the page in a browser, view source, and paste it into your question.

Comment: Put a `debugger;` statement in the function, and open your browser's developer tools and inspect the call stack to see where it's being invoked.

Comment: @cookiemonster - I am using Eclipse for development and test my website in the eclipse browser. Is there a way to inspect the call stack in eclipse ?

Comment: I don't know. Why not use the tools built into your browser? Then you can halt the code as it runs and look at the call stack. to see what invoked the function.

Answer (score 0):

`drawChart` gets executed because of the following line

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: I know that, I mentioned that in the question description. I want to know why procChart is called first and then later on the next script is executed.

Comment: Did you check the js that are included? I am not familiar with the library you are using but seems like that function is called from the javascript files you have included.

Comment: Those are standard libraries which are required for Ajax and jquery implementation. I don't think these standard libraries will call a user defined function automatically.

Comment: Generally in these situations I use Developer Tools and set breakpoint  inside the function and see the call stack.